# Using PurgeCSS, TailwindCSS, and Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, purge, tailwind-css

I am trying to set up webpack for a static site built with TailwindCSS. I am trying to use PurgeCSS to make my css file and get rid of anything unused and I do not believe it is working. It will compile with no errors but the css file is 16kb and Google lighthouse audit says there is unused css.

webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require("path");
    const glob = require("glob-all");
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
    const PurgecssPlugin = require("purgecss-webpack-plugin");

    /**
     * Custom PurgeCSS Extractor
     * https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss
     * https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-webpack-plugin
     */
    class TailwindExtractor {
      static extract(content) {
        return content.match(/[A-z0-9-:\/]+/g);
      }
    }

    module.exports = {
      entry: "./index.js",
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "styles.css"
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: "style-loader",
              use: [{ loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } }, "postcss-loader"]
            })
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new PurgecssPlugin({
          paths: glob.sync([
            path.join(__dirname, "src/styles.css"),
            path.join(__dirname, "index.html")
          ]),
          extractors: [
            {
              extractor: TailwindExtractor,
              extensions: ["html", "js"]
            }
          ]
        })
      ]
    };
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ajv": "^6.5.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "postcss": "^6.0.14",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
        "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^0.6.4",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "glob-all": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Are you're using Google Chrome? When DevTools are open, hit the ESC-Key and select "[Coverage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage)" in the dropdown menu. There you can inspect, which CSS is used/unused.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to compile your code with `npm build` or `yarn build` ?

If you go to the TailwindCSS documentation unter "Process your CSS with Tailwind" there is section "Using Tailwind with PostCSS" and there is a template repository linked, where you can see how it can be done.
First thing that I see is that your entry point is your index.js and in the template repo its `./src/styles.css`.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiled CSS is just 16Kb then PurgeCSS is definitely working, without it Tailwind would be outputting something ~300Kb.